# Social Login, Authentication and Authorization using Auth0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, auth0

I am using Auth0 for social logins. Here are the steps which I have accomplished so far:

1. Perform social login on frontend angular web site and IDP returns
   me a short-lived token.
2. Send this short token to a rest api that gathers user information from Auth0 and stores in the database

Now I want to authenticate user via request #2, but I am not sure how to approach this, as every authentication sample seems to deal with username and password.

Comment: What kind of user information are you referring to? Are you looking to call the `userinfo` endpoint (https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#get-user-info)? Or are you calling your own API that has information about the user? If that's the case we can setup your API in Auth0 (more info here: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/api-tokens) or even you can look to store that info about the user in Auth0 in `usermetadata`. With a bit more details I can suggest a more well rounded solution/answer!

Comment: Hey @kimcodes, I have devised a solution, just need to check if that's fine. I created an angular client that interacts with auth0 and authenticates identity using social logins. Once I am successfully authenticated, I receive an Auth0 access token which I send to my rest api for validation and it returns me a JWT token to be used in rest of API calls. Is this solution fine?

Comment: sorry @harrisunderwork I only saw this now! that sounds about right to me :) you can also share your solution at community.auth0.com you may get more help specific to auth0, if ever you don't get help on stackoverflow